# How to fix DNS cache poisoning on EC2 with NGINX

Tags: nginx

After setting up HTTPS, I recently discovered that my domain is the victim of a cache poisoning attack.  My server is an EC2 running an NGINX server to serve a Django app.

The server would intermittently throw a 403 error on the home page, and when I manually enter the login URL, I get a 404 error.  In the DevTools console I get the following message:

> (index):22 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.safespreadsheets.com/login/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.iyfipgun.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.safespreadsheets.com/login/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure resource
>   'http://www.iyfipgun.com/?dn=www.safespreadsheets.com&pid=9POL6F2H4'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I searched for a way to solve the issue and it looks like it has to do with the way that NGINX deals with its DNS cache.  I haven't yet found a way to flush the cache (as a starting point) and I don't know how to ensure that the cache doesn't get poisoned again.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I was asked how I came to the conclusion that this was DNS cache poisoning after setting up HTTPS.

I investigated all potential issues that would yield intermittent 403/404 errors, fixed everything that could remotely be wrong.  It was only after I set up HTTPS that the 404 error (manually entering the login page) yielded the Mixed Content message indicated above. I know that none of my resources would be served as HTTP, and I googled the domain, finding that it is a spam site.

to prove the point, here is a screenshot of the page call showing that the 404 page isn't from my IP address:

[image]

Comment: You implement DNSSEC.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you determined that your observation about the https-transported content is related to DNS cache poisoning?

Comment: @anx by way of elimination really, and it may well be that my deduction is incorrect but based on the behaviour of the system it seems most likely.  I fixed and patched everything that could potentially cause the issue (including properly serving static files and a weird issue with my A records).  It was only when I saw the reference to a known spam site that I identified the possible issue.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks...I hoped there was something simpler.  DNSSEC seems super complicated (I am more a coder than a system administrator obviously)

Comment: Some of the major DNS providers have already integrated DNSSEC so all you really need to do is take two minutes to turn it on. Others are... seriously lagging (like Route 53).

Answer (score 1):

Following Michael Hampton's advice, I spoke to my DNS provider and we were able to sort the problem out.  The DNS is now secure and the site works as expected.